# measuring specific bodyparts using EmguCv HaarCascade

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

I'm trying to develop a program that measures the shoulder width of the user, and I have encountered multiple problems which I don't know how to solve.

1. When I capture the whole body picture of the user using the laptop's webcam the system gives incorrect measurements
2. I tried capturing 3 images of the same user with the same distance and etc. but when I started measuring them it gives inconsistent measurement.

Here is my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Emgu.CV;
    using Emgu.CV.Structure;
    using Emgu.Util;

    namespace fitting
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            HaarCascade UpperBody = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml");
            HaarCascade LowerBody = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_lowerbody.xml");
        Capture camera;
        bool captureProcess = false;
        Image<Bgr, Byte> img;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void viewImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            img = camera.QueryFrame();
            if (img == null)
                return;
            CamImageBox.Image = img;
        }

        private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (captureProcess == true)
            {
                string data;

                Application.Idle -= viewImage;
                captureProcess = false;
                SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    img.ToBitmap().Save(dlg.FileName + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    data = dlg.FileName + ".bmp";
                }
                measureImage();
            }
        }

        void measureImage()
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg2 = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg2.Filter = "Image|*.Bmp";
            if (dlg2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = new Image<Bgr, byte>(dlg2.FileName);
                Image<Gray, Byte> Gray_Frame = frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();


/////////////////////////LOWER BODY DETECTION////////////////////////////////
                MCvAvgComp[][] LowerBodyDetect = Gray_Frame.DetectHaarCascade(
                    LowerBody,
                    1.985603925968,
                    0,
                    Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                    new Size());

///////////////////HERE IS THE UPPER BODY DETECTION/////////////////////////

                MCvAvgComp[][] UpperBodyDetect = Gray_Frame.DetectHaarCascade(
                    UpperBody,
                    1.3,
                    5,
                    Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                    new Size());


/////////////////////////DRAWING OF RECTANGLE ON DETECTED UPPER BODY///////////////////
                try
                {
                    frame.Draw(UpperBodyDetect[0][0].rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                    double width = (UpperBodyDetect[0][0].rect.Width);
                    textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToString(width));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
///////////////////////DRAWING OF RECTANGLE ON DETECTED LOWER BODY///////////////////
                try
                {
                    frame.Draw(LowerBodyDetect[0][0].rect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 2);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
                CamImageBox.Image = frame;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool useCam = true;

            if (!useCam)
                measureImage();
            else {
                try
                {
                    camera = new Capture();
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                    return;
                }
                Application.Idle += viewImage;
                captureProcess = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```